# NA in clustering functions (kmeans, pam, clara). How to associate clusters to original data?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, na, missing-data

I need to cluster some data and I tried `kmeans`, `pam`, and `clara` with R.

The problem is that my data are in a column of a data frame, and contains NAs.

I used `na.omit()` to get my clusters. But then how can I associate them with the original data? The functions return a vector of integers without the NAs and they don't retain any information about the original position.

Is there a clever way to associate the clusters to the original observations in the data frame? (or a way to intelligently perform clustering when NAs are present?)

Thanks

Comment: have you named your rows? i think kmeans and pam (at least) keep the row names, don't they?

Comment: I do this way: kmeans(na.omit(x), k)

Comment: The cluster vectors (e.g. `clus$cluster`) corresponds to the non-`NA` elements of `x`. So the indices of `x` that the elements of `clus$cluster` correspond to are `which(!is.na(x))`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The output of `kmeans` corresponds to the elements of the object passed as argument `x`. In your case, you omit the `NA` elements, and so `$cluster` indicates the cluster that each element of `na.omit(x)` belongs to.

Here's a simple example:

```
d <- data.frame(x=runif(100), cluster=NA)
d$x[sample(100, 10)] <- NA
clus <- kmeans(na.omit(d$x), 5)

d$cluster[which(!is.na(d$x))] <- clus$cluster
```

And in the plot below, colour indicates the cluster that each point belongs to.

```
plot(d$x, bg=d$cluster, pch=21)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me, starting with a matrix containing a whole row of NAs:

```
DF=matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)
row.names(DF) <- paste("r", 1:10, sep="")
DF[3,]<-NA
res <- kmeans(na.omit(DF), 3)$cluster
res
DF=cbind(DF, 'clus'=NA)
DF[names(res),][,11] <- res
print(DF[,11])
```